# Can I make the Eclipse source formatter preserve the original spacing around operators?

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes I like to space an expression non-uniformly. E.g., I prefer...

```
x*x + y*y
```

...to...

```
x * x + y * y
```

It seems that the Eclipse formatter won't allow this. I can tell it to put either zero or one space around every operator, but I can't see how to make it leave the spacing as I wrote it. Can this be done? (`@formatter:off` is too intrusive.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the formatter formats, unconditionally.

Comment: That's a rather sweeping statement. The "never join already wrapped lines" setting makes formatting conditional in the same way. I was hoping for a similar "trust the programmer" setting for this kind of whitespace.

Comment: @MartinStone Obviously when there are options available, it uses those options--when there aren't, it can't.

Comment: @MartinStone Parens would be superfluous in the "for" statement you show; communication is not enhanced. Communication *is* enhanced when precedence comes in to play.

Comment: Sure -- Just wondering if I'd missed something, since the formatter seems so fine-grained and highly configurable generally.

Comment: @MartinStone Meh, I've never found the Eclipse formatter to be very good, ashleigh the last two revs aren't bad. Maybe check out Jalopy and see if it does what you want and skip formatting via Ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. On a skim of the docs it looks like Jalopy has a similar either/or approach. (Fiddling with the source is a step too far for me, I think.)  If you don't mind, I'm going to edit your (accepted) answer and remove the off-topic parenthesis discussion. You might like to prune your comments too, so that it all makes sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

```
Window -> Preference -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter -> Edit -> White Space -> Expressions -> Operators
```

and then check the following 2 check boxes:

```
☑ before binary operators
☑ after binary operators
```

Comment: Unfortunately that removes all spaces, giving me `x*x+y*y`.

Comment: Un-checked gives me `x*x+y*y` and checked gives me `x * x + y * y`. I was hoping for a setting to say "leave the spacing as originally written".